# Error while Navigating from Window to page in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, navigation

I read around hundreds of Q/A & Blogs for the same, but not able to resolve the error I am getting. In my WPF application I need to navigate from a MainWindow.xaml to a Page Register.xaml. I have below code :

```
        Register register = new Register();
        MainWindow.Navigate(register);
```

Or

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Register.xaml ", UriKind.Relative));
```

It is giving me error
'.MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'Navigate'
Or
MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'NavigationService'

Comment: Are you trying to open the page in a new window or as content in a the current window?

Comment: as content in a the current window

Answer (score 0):

To open a [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in you need to have it in a [frame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> ```
> A page can be hosted from Window, NavigationWindow, Frame, or from a browser. To be hosted, a page can be:
> ```

- The direct child of a Window, NavigationWindow, or Frame element in
  XAML.
- Instantiated and set as the value of the Content property of Window, NavigationWindow, and Frame.
- Set as the uniform resource identifier (URI) source of the Source property of either NavigationWindow or Frame.

If you want to have it in your MainWindow you can do the following.

XAML

```
<Frame Name="contentFrame" />
```

C# code-behind

```
contentFrame.Content = new Page();
```

To open it in a new window you could do something like this.

```
Page p = new Page();
p.Show();
```